# XWiki request handling ( without form if possible )

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, request, xwiki

Is it possible to handle requests on XWiki other way than just with submitting HTML forms ? I need to use XMLHttpRequest, but `$request`
simply doesn 't react to the request.

#### JavaScript code

```
function requestHandle(msg, subj) {
    var recipientName = recipientsArr.pop()[0];

    req = new XMLHttpRequest();

    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (req.readyState == 4) {
            if (req.status == 200) {
                console.log('req ok');

                var mailStatusTmp = "<div class=\"mailStatus\">" + recipientName + " <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok\"/></div>";
                $('#mailStatusWrapper').append(mailStatusTmp);

                if (recipientsArr.length > 0) {
                    requestHandle(msg, subj); // call requestHandle() for next recipient
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                console.log('req err');

                var mailStatusTmp = "<div class=\"mailStatus\">" + recipientName + " <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove\"/></div>";
                $('#mailStatusWrapper').append(mailStatusTmp);

                if (recipientsArr.length > 0) {
                    requestHandle(msg, subj); // call requestHandle() for next recipient
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    req.open("POST", "https://wiki.intra.tieto.com/xwiki/bin/view/Sandbox/TestPage1", true);
    req.send("msg=" + msg + "&subj=" + subj + "&recipientName=" + recipientName);
}
```

I want to use XMLHttpRequest, because the page will send data to multiple receivers and I need to check the status every request.

Answer (score 0):

If the page making the request is not on the same domain as the XWiki instance, then you might have to configure the target domain to accept [cross-origin](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) requests. That's not easy to do on XWiki's side, since there's no mechanism for responding to `OPTION` requests, but it's easy to configure if you're using a frontend, such as [Apache HTTPD](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled#For_Apache) or [nginx](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled#For_nginx), or in the servlet container's configuration, for example in [Tomcat](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled#For_Apache_Tomcat_.287.0.41_and_above.29) or [Jetty](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled#For_Jetty_.287_and_above.29).

Comment: xwiki enterprise (with installer) seems to come with jetty, should i modify the web.xml under jetty\contexts\ to allow cross-origin request or modify the web.xml under xwiki\WEB-INF, and...how should i modify?